# Swift set height of table

Tags: swift, uitableview, height, swift3, contentsize

I have this table for which I want a certain height even when I only have one row. I want to make it scrollable (empty space at the bottom) even when I do not have enough rows to cover the whole screen.

I think I should work with:

```
tableView.contentSize.height = 2000
```

But either I do not know where I should put it(should I reloadData for the table after?) or I have the wrong idea of how to do this.

Can anybody help?

EDIT: I have this view inside the table view which in some cases might be higher than the table and in this case I can not scroll it all. This is why I need to change the table in scroll height.

On iOS 10 it works as intended, but I have to fix it for iOS 8 and 9 also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only at this hour at night have I realised what works. I can't set the height of the content size directly, but like this:

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

var contentSizeTemp = tableView.contentSize
contentSizeTemp.height = menuViewHeight.constant 
tableView.contentSize = contentSizeTemp
```

Answer (score 4):

This has been tested and works:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.contentSize.height = 2000
}
```

Example: 
[image]

Comment: What if I need to do this when something changes after the screen is loaded, for example when a user taps a button?

Comment: You can simply call `tableView.contentSize.height = 2000`. You do not need to call `reloadData()` unless the data has actually changed. In which case you would want to call `reloadData()` then set the `contentSize`.

Comment: Doesn't work on iOS 9 when there are no rows in the table view... Any other ideas?

Comment: @asheyla that's very odd. I've tested on a device running iOS 9 and it works fine. It runs fine the the simulator as well. Can you post more of your implementation? I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to show me the example.  I thought tableView.tableFooterView = UIView() might be the reason why your solution wasn't working for me so I deleted it and still it doesn't work as intended. I see you have declared reloadContent(). Do you call it anywhere?

Comment: @asheyla `reloadContent()` is called when my left `barButtonItem` is pressed. If you'd like to post your project or a create a test project that replicates your issue I can take a look at it. Otherwise, I'm not sure how else I can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125424/discussion-between-asheyla-and-random).

Comment: Only at this hour at night have I realised what works. I can't set the height of the content size directly, but like this:

    var contentSizeTemp = tableView.contentSize
            contentSizeTemp.height = menuViewHeight.constant
            tableView.contentSize = contentSizeTemp

Comment: @asheyla I'm not sure why that works since it's just a convoluted way of doing `tableView.contentSize.height = menuViewHeight.constant` but happy you were able to get it to work.

Comment: I realised when I started cleaning the code of all the previous tries to make this work that this was also needed: tableView.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

What about setting constraints for table view? Or it's another case when they are not suitable?
In this case table will have height which is equal screen height no matter how much rows it has.
[image]

Comment: I have edited my question, I hope it now gives more explanation. It's the in scroll height that interests me, the height of the table is ok, it sits where it should and covers as much screen as I need.